# Group by por fecha usando left join mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy  tratando de hacer una consulta que implica 3 tablas, post,  comentarios y likes. necesito saber la fecha del post y el titulo del post, el número de personas que han comentado el post y el numero de likes por cada persona, el detalle está en que necesito hacer group by con la fecha de los comentarios y los likes de cada persona para hacer unas estadisca con los valores que obtengo con los datos de los likes y comentarios por persona. si no existe un valor en la tabla "comentarios o likes" lo reemplazaría por 0.

**Tablas y datos**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`titulo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );

INSERT INTO `post` (`id`, `titulo`, `user_id`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 'group by mysql', 19, '2018-02-18 19:10:30');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comentarios` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );

INSERT INTO `comentarios` (`id`, `content`, `post_id`, `user_id`,    `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 'comentario 1', 1, 19, '2018-02-19 13:12:09'),
(2, 'comentario 2', 1, 20, '2018-02-20 23:42:09'),
(3, 'comentario 3', 1, 19, '2018-02-21 19:12:30'),
(4, 'comentario 4', 1, 21, '2018-02-26 11:38:34'),
(5, 'comentario 5', 1, 22, '2018-02-28 19:13:15');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 );

INSERT INTO `likes` (`id`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 19, '2018-02-28 19:16:12'),
(2, 1, 21, '2018-02-28 19:16:12'),
(3, 1, 22, '2018-02-22 19:16:21');
```

***EDIT***

He avanzado en la consulta, aun me falta lograr que si hay likes en una fecha que no hay comentarios los comentarios y el contador de los comentarios salga en null o 0.
de igual forma si hay un comentario en el fecha que no hay likes que los likes salgan en null o 0.

**consulta actual**

```
 SELECT
 p.id as post_id,
 titulo,
 MAX(DATE(p.created_at)) as fecha_post,
 MAX(DATE(c.created_at)) as fecha_comentario,
 COUNT(c.user_id) as count_personas,
 MAX(DATE(l.created_at)) as fecha_likes,
COUNT(l.user_id) as count_likes
  FROM post as p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comentarios as c 
   ON p.id=c.post_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN likes as l
    ON p.id=l.post_id and date(c.created_at)=date(l.created_at)
  GROUP BY p.id, DATE(p.created_at), DATE(c.created_at), DATE(l.created_at);
```

**update campos**

```
UPDATE  likes
SET created_at='2018-02-22 14:46:21'
WHERE id=3
```

**salida que espero**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien podria ayudarme a terminar la consulta y obtener el resultado deseado?

Comment: Haz hecho un enunciado bastante detallado, pero sería mejor si pudieras agregar un ejemplo de la salida que esperas? es mejor no suponer, y ser más especifico.

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon he agregado una salida de lo que espero gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon bro, he editado el post por favor si puedes asisteme a ver si se puede lograr el resultado deseado.

Comment: La única forma de relacionar likes y comentarios es añadiendo una clave foranea de comentario en likes.

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon estuve viendo y creo q es posible haciendo un union all y  join, de tal manera que se pueda emular un full outher join

Answer (score 3):

Para poder hacerlo, te hace falta hacer una serie de cambios:

1. La tabla `comentarios` debe tener una PRIMARY KEY bien definida.
2. Relacionar la tabla `likes` con la de `comentarios`.

Te dejo la estructura de las dos tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `comentarios` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `likes` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `comment_idx` (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

No te olvides de agregar los valores de la columna `comment_id` que relacionan la tabla `likes` con `comentarios`, ejemplo:

```
UPDATE likes SET comment_id = 5 WHERE comment_id = 0;
```

**La consulta deseada:**

```
SELECT
  p.id as post_id,
  DATE(p.created_at) as fecha_post,
  c.user_id AS usuario_comentario,
  DATE(c.created_at) as fecha_comentario,
  COUNT(c.user_id) as count_personas,
  DATE(l.created_at) as fecha_likes,
  COUNT(l.user_id) as count_likes
FROM post as p
LEFT JOIN comentarios as c 
       ON p.id=c.post_id
LEFT JOIN likes as l
       ON p.id=l.post_id AND l.comment_id = c.id
GROUP BY p.id, DATE(p.created_at), DATE(c.created_at), DATE(l.created_at);
```

**Salida deseada:**

```
+---------+------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| post_id | fecha_post | usuario_comentario | fecha_comentario | count_personas | fecha_likes | count_likes |
+---------+------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | 2018-02-18 |                 19 | 2018-02-19       |              1 | NULL        |           0 |
|       1 | 2018-02-18 |                 20 | 2018-02-20       |              1 | NULL        |           0 |
|       1 | 2018-02-18 |                 19 | 2018-02-21       |              1 | NULL        |           0 |
|       1 | 2018-02-18 |                 21 | 2018-02-26       |              1 | NULL        |           0 |
|       1 | 2018-02-18 |                 22 | 2018-02-28       |              3 | 2018-03-01  |           3 |
+---------+------------+--------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: @JoseeNaava Te dejo un ejemplo, si me puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que esperas es mejor, cualquier me encargo de arreglar esta respuesta.

Comment: me ayudas? aun no he terminado de resolver la consulta